# ASPX not accessing Javascript.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Doing some javascript for the first time.
I'm playing around with a sessiontimeout and it was working well while I had the code within the .aspx page.
Next stape was to put the code in a .js page. So here's my current lineup.

**Script.aspx.js**

```
    var iddleTimeoutWarning = null;
    var iddleTimeout = null;
function pageLoad() 
{     
    if (iddleTimeoutWarning != null)
        clearTimeout(iddleTimeoutWarning);
    if (iddleTimeout != null)
        clearTimeout(iddleTimeout);    
    var millisecTimeOutWarning = <%= int.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionTimeoutWarning"]) * 60 * 1000 %>;
    var millisecTimeOut = <%= int.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionTimeout"]) * 60 * 1000 %>; 
    iddleTimeoutWarning = setTimeout("DisplayIddleWarning()", millisecTimeOutWarning);
    iddleTimeout = setTimeout("TimeoutPage()", millisecTimeOut);
} 

function DisplayIddleWarning() 
{                
    document.getElementById("LblWarning").innerHTML = "Warning Message";
} 

function TimeoutPage() 
{                   
    __doPostBack('FiresAutoIdle','');
}
```

ASPX page (Pretty sure error is here since the code in .js page works)

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>            
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="Scripts/Script.aspx.js"/>
        </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

I also have some code lines in web.config to set keys SessionTimeout and SessionTimeoutWarning.

So, any idea on where's the glitch? Things used to run, now they won't.

**EDIT**

1. I'm using a script manager for a quick handling of the necessary ASP.NET AJAX components to enable partial postback. I need __doPostBack.
2. I found out if a js function is named pageLoad(), the function will activate when the page loads or when a partial postback. Just what I need.

So, asp.nex page is not loading pageLoad() function from .js.

Comment: If you hit Scripts/Script.aspx.js separately in the browser, does it render as you expect? Just wondering if you need to use ScriptManager, or whether you'd be better off including the rendered js results using a client-side <script> tag.

Comment: @BenParsons If I chrome-open the .js file I get plain text, the code itself.

Comment: You mean opening it as a file? Or hitting it when running a server locally? Those are different things. IMO, you probably don't need to use ScriptManager. If you can get the file to output as you need it to then that will fix a lot of your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

You can't set asp variables inside of javascript. So we have to set the variables in ASPX page, and then let javascript use them.

ASPX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var millisecTimeOutWarning = <%= int.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionTimeoutWarning"]) * 60 * 1000 %>;
    var millisecTimeOut = <%= int.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionTimeout"]) * 60 * 1000 %>; 
</script>
```

Then use them in .js file.